# EF 4.5 .tt file that has the POCO entities

Tags: poco, t4, edmx, entity-framework-5

I want to place two using directives in a EF 4.5 edmx .tt file and am having trouble. The 4.0 syntax was different and easier to manipulate.

Any help would be appreciated.... 
EF 4.0 syntax:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
```

4.5 syntax

```
public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
    {
        return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
            ? string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}using System;{1}" +
                "{2}",
                inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
                includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
                inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
            : "";
    }
```

I need to add the following attributes in the .tt file:

EF 4.0 syntax

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
<#
```

4.5 syntax

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }
```

4.0 syntax

```
void WriteProperty(string accessibility, string type, string name, string getterAccessibility, string setterAccessibility)
{
#> [DataMember]
    <#=accessibility#> <#=type#> <#=name#> { <#=getterAccessibility#>get; <#=setterAccessibility#>set; }
<#+
}
```

4.5 syntax
I can't find any similiar syntax**

Basically, I want the output of the class when it's regenerated from the edmx file to look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization; using System.ServiceModel; 
namespace YeagerTechModel
{
   [Serializable] 
   [DataContract(IsReference = true)]    
   public partial class Priority 
    {
        public Priority()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

     [DataMember]         
     public short PriorityID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]         
     public string Description { get; set; }
     [DataMember]         
     public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you serious that you don't understand the code and you don't know how to change it? It is just a string formatting ... Even if you don't understand the formatting you can still update template directly as you did in the previous version so you even don't understand how text templating works. You should really spend some time on basic tutorials.

Here you have some examples

Usings:

```
public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
{
    var usings = new List<string>() {
        "using System;",
        "using System.Runtime.Serialization;",
        "using System.ServiceModel;"
    };

    if (includeCollections) {
        usings.Add("using System.Collections.Generic;");
    }

    return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
        ? string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}{1}{2}",
            inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
            String.Join(Environment.NewLine, usings),
            inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
        : "";
}
```

Class:

```
public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
{
    const string attributes = "[Serializable,  DataContract(IsReference = true)]";

    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0}{1}{2} {3}partial class {4}{5}",
        attributes,
        Environment.NewLine,
        Accessibility.ForType(entity),
        _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
        _code.Escape(entity),
        _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
}
```

Properties:

```
public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "[DataMember] {0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
        _code.Escape(edmProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
}

public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
{
    var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "[DataMember] {0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForProperty(navigationProperty)),
        navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
        _code.Escape(navigationProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navigationProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navigationProperty)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my issue. I knew what the code was doing, but didn't know how to implement the new items I needed to add. I guess if I did some research on each of the method names for the edmx templates, maybe I could have figured it out. But honestly, there was no way I would have known WHERE to place the attribute code in each of the methods if you hadn't supplied the sample. Now, going forward, as far as the templating goes, I have an idea, thanks to your sample, and will incorporate this logic going forward.

Comment: I agree that some templating logic would have been appropriate for me to find out more about, but after researching, I couldn't find anything (obvioulsy, I didn't search on the correct keywords). I'm also a person that learns a lot my example. You show me something once how to do it in an example, and I can take that concept forward as you demonstrated.